# Difference between program account and program executable data account

Tags: solana-program, beginner

so recently I was playing around with Solana and trying to understand how it works, the high-level understanding. Tho the mechanism is fascinatingly hard to understand, I was trying to understand it with an example. When I came across, two accounts upon deploying the contract, I am not understanding what is the difference between a  program account and a program executable data account.
Where is the instruction stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program account is literally just the address of the program executable data account.  This was a bit of a hack introduced when the upgradeable loader was added.  Executable accounts were normally not allowed to have their data changed, so the added level of indirection allowed the loader to bypass the runtime checks.

Everything is stored in the program data account, including the compiled bytecode of your program. Only the instruction parsing and interpreting is "stored" in the bytecode, influencing how your program reacts to data sent into it.  No actual instructions are stored there.

Comment: Is there documentation where I can read more about this? So the "executable data account" is what stores the majority of the bytecode, and the program account stores some barebones parsing bytecode?

Comment: Certainly! Please read through https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/deploying#overview-of-the-upgradeable-bpf-loader